# SQL2008r2 Performance - ORDER BY is slow for small result set (25 rows, 20 columns)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-order-by, query-performance

I have a query that takes the form:

```
SELECT [Col1], [Col2], ..., [ColX]
FROM ( *** VERY LARGE QUERY WITH LOTS OF JOINS ***) [Src]
```

Now, this query finishes almost instantenously returning 25 rows, but if I append ORDER BY in the end, then it hangs:

```
SELECT [Col1], [Col2], ..., [ColX]
FROM ( *** VERY LARGE QUERY WITH LOTS OF JOINS ***) [Src]
ORDER BY [Col1], [Col2], [Col3], [Col4]
```

Same happens if I do:

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT [Col1], [Col2], ..., [ColX]
FROM ( *** VERY LARGE QUERY WITH LOTS OF JOINS ***) [Src]) [Src]
ORDER BY [Col1], [Col2], [Col3], [Col4]
```

But the query performs almost if I do instaneously:

```
SELECT * INTO #TempTable FROM (
SELECT [Col1], [Col2], ..., [ColX]
FROM ( *** VERY LARGE QUERY WITH LOTS OF JOINS ***) [Src]) [Src]

SELECT * FROM #TempTable
ORDER BY [Col1], [Col2], [Col3], [Col4]
```

I checked the execution plan and it apparently tried to do an Index Seek and Key Lookup on one of the source tables deep within the query. Since the ORDER BY should only be concerned with those 25 rows, I am stumped as to why it'd even care to look at the indexing of parent tables. Any ideas?

Comment: Clustered indexes will go a long way in getting your order by query out quicker.

Comment: Yeah but it doens't make sense, since it's just all about sorting the output.

Comment: Is there anywhere in the query plan where the expected number of rows seriously mismatches the actual number of rows?  And if so, can you update statistics to fix it?

Comment: UpdateStatistics does work as a band-aid fix but as soon as the table gets updated again, the problem recurs.

Comment: It sounds like there is a problem using indexes then.  You're adding a lot of good information about why it should work.  But it seems like the engine isn't making consistent choices.  This does suggest challenges around maintaining indexes.  It would be great to see the query plans around those variations - maybe especially where it runs fast after Update Statistics and then runs slow again.  And then check fragmentation and we can say more.

Comment: That's a good point. I've defragmented it before and that didn't work but I will try it again just to make sure.